# Micronaut CORS allowedOrigins from evnironment variable

Tags: cors, micronaut

I am currently building a microservice with Micronaut. now I want to add CORS support. At the moment my application.yml looks like this:

```
micronaut:
  application:
    name: gateway
  server:
    port: ${HTTP_PORT:8080}
    cors:
      enabled: true
      configurations:
        web:
          allowedOrigins:
            - http://localhost:8080
```

Is there a way to pass the allowedOrigins as an array from an environment variable?

Comment: Did you try `MICRONAUT_SERVER_CORS_CONFIGURATIONS_WEB_ALLOWED_ORIGINS="http://localhost:8080,http://localhost:8081"`?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have tried this, but it only works with a single Host, if I add two hosts, it doesn't work.

I have it like this in my application.yml:
`allowedOrigins: ${CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS}`

And the env:
`CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS=http://localhost:4000,http://localhost:4001`

Answer (score 0):

Set your env variables like `MICRONAUT_SERVER_CORS_CONFIGURATIONS_WEB_ALLOWED_ORIGINS[0]=http://localhost:8080 MICRONAUT_SERVER_CORS_CONFIGURATIONS_WEB_ALLOWED_ORIGINS[1]=http://other.host`.

Setting your config like:

```
micronaut:
  server:
    cors:
      configurations:
        web:
          allowedOrigins: ${ALLOWED_ORIGINS}
```

and setting your env variable like `ALLOWED_ORIGINS=http://localhost:8080,http://other.host` should also work.

Comment: Thanks. Sadly it doesn't work with both variants. I have now set multiple env variables with empty string as default, so I can set them if needed, but it is not really a pretty solution.